# Loop over results from a query to use in another query

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which returns a specific data set

```
select user_id, county from users
```

Primary key is on `user_id, county`

Lets say this returns the following:

```
1   "HARRIS NORTH"
1   "HANOVER"
3   "MARICOPA"
4   "ADAMS"
5   "CUMBERLAND"
```

Next, I want to run a different set of query for all the records I obtain from the above query.

```
COPY( WITH myconstants (_id, _county) as (
   values (1, 'HARRIS NORTH')
)
 SELECT d.* FROM data d, myconstants
where user_id = _id and county = _county) 
TO '/tmp/filename.csv' (format CSV);
```

How can I do this in a loop for all the records from my 1st query using postgres only?

A psuedocode of what I want to achieve:

```
for (a_id, a_county) in (select user_id, county from users):
    COPY( WITH myconstants (_id, _county) as (
        values (a_id, a_county))
    SELECT d.* FROM data d, myconstants
        where user_id = _id and county = _county) 
        TO '/tmp/filename.csv' (format CSV);
```

Comment: You cannot have `WITH` with `COPY`, but with the `SELECT`: `COPY (WITH ... AS (...) SELECT ...) TO ...;`.

Comment: So that's not the solution you are looking for? I guess I don't understand your question then.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am looking for a way to loop through the result of my 1st query and use those in the where clause of 2nd query.

Comment: @hsnsd you mean, in place of `myconstants`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. In my example I have hard coded values in `myconstants`. I need these to come from my 1st query in a loop.

Comment: So just put your first query in that `with` statement? Or even drop the `with` altogether and just select `from users` instead of `from myconstants`. There are no loops in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop in SQL:

```
COPY (SELECT d.*
      FROM data d
         JOIN users
            ON d.user_id = users.user_id AND d.country = users.country) 
TO '/tmp/filename.csv' (format CSV);
```

Comment: I want a separate file per (id,county). This would just create one file.

Comment: You didn't say so. That cannot be done with a single `COPY` statement.